# Move gradient handles for all objects

Tags: inkscape, gradient

I have a gradient that I want to apply to many objects, and for each object I want to move the handles in the same way. Is there a way to apply these changes to a single object and to have the change applied across all objects using the same gradient?

The edit gradient tool allows me to, say, change the colour across all objects using the same gradient, but moving the handles of one objects does not change the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select multiple objects using the Select by Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd> by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click, to select each object.

Then, while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click, you can select multiple handles. Then click and drag and move them as one.

Example

[image]

Another possible solution, if all the objects are the same shape, is to create Clones, and edit the gradient in the Clone source, then it will apply to all instances of the Clone.

Example

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thanks!